Movie about the journey of afterlife
I may have seen this drama/black-comedy movie back in 2005.
The plot revolves around the story three characters, two men and one girl seeking peace after they have died. Something like purgatory.
I remember the name of one of the characters the protagonists his name is Zia.
All the characters in the movie have died either accident or suicide. In this world, Zia works in a restaurant. I'm not sure how he died.
The other man has a car in which they drive endlessly, trying to reach somewhere I forgot. But they keep listening to a single song all the way. I remember this car having a black hole or something like that because the girl gets sick of hearing the same song over and gets rid of the tape by throwing it in this black hole. 
I think this song they keep playing is in English but song by a guy with a Russian accent.
I think they are meant to meet some sort of a God or an angel to decide whether the should regain their life again or not.
At the end of the movie the girl gets her life back, I do know how deserves to get life after committing suicide but that's what's happened. Zia also gets his life back for some reason.

Sounds like Wristcutters: A Love Story from 2006:

When his girlfriend Desiree breaks up with him, the heartbroken Zia commits suicide cutting his wrists. He awakes in the arid Beyond, a dark place inhabited by suicidal people and worst than the world of the living. He finds a job in the pizzeria Kamikaze, sharing a room with a weird roommate. When Zia meets a former friend, he is informed that Desiree has also committed suicide a couple of months after his death. He befriends the Russian guitarist Eugene, who died electrocuted in a rock concert, and together they decide to seek out Desiree. 

It was based on a short story (which was also a graphic novel). Here's the trailer:




Yes, indeed. The name of this movie bothered me a lot ever since i saw it... Thanks
